# Rake mysql2 "unknown database" error

Tags: rake, mysql2

I'm following instructions from a hand-over package from a previous group. I don't know too much about rails or mysql2. I am on Windows.

When I do:

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

This is the output:

```
C:\jcccf-goslowserver-e30bf00>rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
(in C:/jcccf-goslowserver-e30bf00)
rake aborted!
Unknown database 'goslow_production'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.r
b:37:in `connect'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.r
b:37:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/active_record/c
onnection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:14:in `new'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/active_record/c
onnection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:14:in `mysql2_connection'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in `new_connection'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:238:in `checkout_new_connection'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:194:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in `loop'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in `block in checkout'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:189:in `checkout'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:96:in `connection'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:318:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:97:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:486:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:433:in `new'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:433:in `up'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/migrati
on.rb:415:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/railtie
s/databases.rake:142:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `call'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `execute'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:595:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:581:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2041:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2013:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1992:in `run'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'

C:\jcccf-goslowserver-e30bf00>
```

I've read about having to use db:create first but I'm worried that I'll be erasing what's already there from the handover source code. Does this not make sense?

These are the instructions I was given.

```
...
3. Configure your MySQL settings in config/database.yml for "production"
4. Open the console (cmd on Windows, Terminal on Mac/Linux) and cd to the GoSlow directory
5. Type "rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production" and press enter.
6. Type "rake bootstrap:all RAILS_ENV=production" and press enter.
```

(then I assume I just do rails server, it doesn't specify)

Here is my database.yml file which is in config/database.yml relative to where I'm typing these commands.

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
#
# Install the MySQL driver:
#   gem install mysql2
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: GoSlow_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: GoSlow_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: GoSlow_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: [MyPassword]
  host: localhost
```

Any thoughts on why it wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe creating the goslow_production DB

```
CREATE DATABASE goslow_production;
```

Comment: Run `rake db:create` in the terminal and it'll do exactly that in reproducable way (can script it), create for dev and test environment and it's the Rails way and it test the connection between the app and the database.

Answer (score 72):

Running the command

```
rake db:create
```

is enough to avoid the error.

Comment: I second the comment by @ArielCabib. It's more rails specific. As much as possible, we don't want to execute within the database itself.

Comment: Or maybe not - on my setup ANY rake db:... command throws Mysql2::Error: Unknown database